# Solace C++ API for creating Multiple consumers listening to an Exclusive Queue

Tags: c++, solace, solace-mq

Where only 1 Consumer is Active Consumer and others are inactive consumers. If 1 consumer goes down how to make sure other consumer consumes? Code Help is appreciated in C++.

Answer (score 1):

When multiple consumers are connected to an exclusive queue in Solace, your consumers do not have to do anything special in their code to ensure that the inactive consumer comes online when the active consumer goes down.

We do not have a C++ API, but you can use our C API with your C++ application. The C API samples can be downloaded from the Solace [Developer Portal](https://dev.solace.com/downloads/). Refer to the example "HelloWorldQueueSub.c" for a sample queue consumer